# Proving Sylow's second theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sylow's second theorem is as follows:

> **Sylow II**: Let $G$ be a group with $G = p^mr$, with $p$ and $r$ coprime, $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $H$ any $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then there exists $x \in G$ such that $H \subseteq xPx^{-1}$. If $H$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup then $H$ and $P$ are conjugate.

I want to prove the theorem using the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$. Then the number of fixed points in $X$ under the action of $G$ is congruent to $|X| \mod{p}$

I've attempted to prove it, but I didn't use the lemma. However I looked through the proof of the lemma and I did use parts of the proof implicitly. I'd like to know if my proof is correct, and how I would actually directly apply the lemma to prove it.

The $p$-group $H$ acts on $G/P$ by $h\:.\:(gP) = hgP$. Therefore $|G/P| = [G:P] = r$ can be expressed as the sum of the cardinality of its orbits. I pick $g_1P,...,g_nP$ to be the elements of $G/P$ which represent orbits with cardinality more than one; that is, no $g_iP$ is in the same orbit. All other elements which generate orbits with cardinality $1$ (i.e. the fixed points) are collected into a set I'll call $F$. So I can write $[G:P]$ as

$$[G:P] = |F| + |H\:.\:g_1P| + \dots + |H\:.\:g_nP|$$

Now, by the orbit-stabiliser theorem,

$$|H\:.\:g_iP| = \frac{|H|}{|\text{stab}_H(g_iP)|}$$

Since $H$ is a $p$-group, it has cardinality $p^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore by Lagrange, $|\text{stab}_H(g_iP)|$ divides $p^k$. Furthermore since the orbits of the $g_iP$'s have cardinality greater than one, there must be some elements $h \in H$ which don't stabilise $g_iP$ for $i = 1,\dots ,n$. This means that $|\text{stab}_H(g_iP)| < |H|$, therefore

$$\frac{|H|}{|\text{stab}_H(g_iP)|} = p^j \: \text{ for some } 1 \leq j \leq k$$

In particular this means that $p$ divides $|H\:.\:g_iP|$. However since $[G:P] = r$, $p$ doesn't divide $[G:P]$; This means that $F$ contains at least one element.

Let $xP$ be this fixed point in $F$. We have $hxP = xP$ for all $h \in H$, so $x^{-1}Hx \subseteq P$, which is equivalent to $H \subseteq xPx^{-1}$. if $H$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup then $|H| = |P|$ and so $H = xPx^{-1}$.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I specified that in my post. " I'd like to know if my proof is correct, and how I would actually directly apply the lemma to prove it."

Comment: It looks like you used the lemma in the second to last paragraph where you concluded that $F$ is nonempty (you reproved the lemma along the way). Anyway, this appears to be the standard proof of this statement.